# Splat hashtables contained in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, powershell-cmdlet

Given a list of hashtables

```
$adminprinters | ConvertTo-Json

[
    {
        "Brand":  "HP",
        "IP":  "10.8.200.200",
        "Name":  "Admin-Tech-HP4700"
    },
    {
        "Brand":  "HP",
        "IP":  "10.8.200.201",
        "Name":  "Admin-Tech-4015"
    }
]
```

How can I iterate over that list and splat each object to a cmdlet. For example,

```
foreach($h in $adminprinters){
   Add-CustomPrinterModule @($h)
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Add-CustomPrinterModule @h`?

Comment: What have you tried? If you've tried your example, what was the result that you expected, and what did you actually get?

Comment: It works when I omit the () and the $ as Jeroen suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses and the $ must be omitted.

```
foreach($h in $adminprinters){
   Add-CustomPrinterModule @h
   }
```